# Octobercms Plugin model does insert entry on Front End user creation

Tags: octobercms

I'm Trying to create a plugin extension for RainLab User Plugin. I'm using a approach to create separate table for my User data (Extending by Relationship). I want to manage all this myplugin info related to a user in separate database. 
I followed all as per User Plugin extension video. All is working fine.
When a new user is created from backend, it automatically adds entry for its extended profile table and a row is inserted into my table.

But I wanted to create a front end profile update page for same extended data. I've followed component creation video for this and created front end components for this.

Now problem is:
When i update already existing user's extended profile, it updates properly.
But when user is created from front end register component it does not create any extended entry in table. because of which I could not update data from front end for extended profile.

But if I go into Back end and if I open this user entry, it create its entry in my extended table.

I'm not understanding what could be the proble.
Same plugin is working on local server where ive set autoactivate for user.
while on my production server ive kept email activation. 
Files I'm using are here:

https://gist.github.com/bkrajendra/eb5ad3eebe38ae9015dd

Comment: I've resolved the issue. I hope its the proper solution.
Actually backend code is doing this already by making it sure that this profile model is created after user model exists.

Ive called same model function my component code.
`ProfileModel::getFromUser($this->user());` here
$this->user() return a Authenticate user model which is required in getFromUser function to create assign new profile to this user model. Now everything working fine. If anyone having Idea whether is ok or not please suggest.